# Vpython drawing hemisphere

Tags: python, 3d, shapes, vpython

I have a sphere plotted on my program as so:

```
ball=sphere(pos=vector(0,0,0),opacity = 0.5,radius=0.95,color=color.black)
```

Is there any way of making it only show the top half of the sphere?

I'm using vpython.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is make an extrusion. Make your shape a quarter of a circle, then arc the extrusion in a whole 60 degrees. If you see the extrusion examples they have a lot of help about this and so does the documentary of vpython.

ex:

```
    circle = shapes.circle(radius=20) #you can use the size of your choice
    square1 = Polygon[(-10,-20),(-10,20),(0,20),(0,-20)]
    square2 = Polygon[(0,0),(0,20),(20,20),(20,0)]

    rotation = paths.arc(radius=20, angle2=pi)

    Hemisphere = extrusion(pos=rotation,shape=circle-square1-square2)
```

not sure if this is fully syntax error free, etc. but I think you understand the idea behind this. The quarter of a circle get rotated from the centre until it make a complete hemisphere. Hope you get the idea, just did this but for making a full sphere with a chuck taken out as if a slice of cake was out of the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

you could make a box with a black color and make it cover up half the sphere, but other than that I don't know sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear I have done this using extrusions, only I needed a 3/4 of a sphere. Make a half circle shape by calling circle then subtract a square on half the circle. After this make your rotation equal to 1pi (half a circle). Here is how to do it:

```
S1 = shapes.circle(radius=1)

angle = 180  # degrees
angle = angle * (pi/180)  # convert to radians (1pi)

sq = Polygon([(-10, -20), (-10, 20), (0, 20), (0, -20)])
semicircle = paths.arc(radius=0.000000001, angle1=pi/2, angle2=2.2*pi)

mf = frame()
Layer20_Extrusion = extrusion(frame=mf, pos=semicircle, shape=S1-sq, color=wh)

mf.rotate(angle=angle)
mf.pos = (0, 0, 0)
```

You will have to rotate it so that it's the top half missing instead of the side.